# write inner join query in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

i have two tables and need to write this query in django

my models are:

```
class students(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    active = models.BooleanField(max_length=1)

class college(models.Model):
    department = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    s_id = models.ForeignKey(students, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

my mysql query:

```
select b.name,a.department from college as a 
inner join students as b on (a.s_id = b.id) 
where (a.department = 'CSE' AND b.active = 1)
```

i just want to write this query in django

Comment: What you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
college.objects.filter(department='CSE',s_id__active=True).values('s_id__name','department')
```

use this

Comment: i guess his model name is in small letter (college) and not in camelcase(College) @nawarkhede

Comment: what does that "s_id__active=True" do, can you explain a bit please. since i don't have a field name in any of the table.

Comment: @Exprator my mistake. Rectified.

Comment: that for the join to the other table, as you have used s_id as a name for ForeignKey mapping, and for accessing that tables column you have to access it with (dundee, '__') double underscore @msd